# Is it possible to monitor variable changes using a "with" statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the `with` statement to track variable changes, but I'm facing some issues. For instance, I created the code below:

```
class MyContext(object):
    def __init__(self, enter, exit=None):
        self.__enter = enter
        if not exit:
            self.__exit = enter
        else:
            self.__exit = exit
        self.__var = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.__var = eval(self.__enter)
        
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        new_var = eval(self.__exit)

        if new_var != self.__var:
            print("Variable '%s' has changed." % self.__enter)

a = 0

with MyContext(enter="a"):
    a = 2

# Example: a function that returns 
# a different result from input
with MyContext(enter="a", exit="b"):
    b = a
    b = 3
```

The output returns:

```bash
Variable 'a' has changed.
Variable 'a' has changed.
```

The problem I'm facing is I cannot convert `MyContext` class into a module due to `eval()` usage. It breaks the whole logic due to local python interpretation. There are several documents explaining that. So, the question is...

Does anyone know an alternative to do it?

If I need to abandon the `with` statement idea it is OK for me as long as it does not become so complicated for such a small task.

Comment: One option would be to use `ctypes` to modify the `globals()` dictionary if you're using CPython.

Comment: @Mous why `ctypes`?

Comment: The correct solution here is not to try to monitor *variables*, instead, create an object using some custom class which does this sort of monitoring. There are potentially hacky ways to work with actualy variables, but it will be very convoluted and relying on implementation details

Comment: You'd be overriding the class of the dictionary, like `ctypes.py_object.from_address(id(globals())+8).value=some_custom_class`. I've got some code lying around somewhere from Python Discord where it was achieved. I don't recommend doing this, but it's the only solution I can see.

Comment: I don't understand what *problem you are trying to solve*, or *goal you are trying to achieve* by doing such monitoring.

Comment: module `tkinter` uses for this special objects instead of normal variables - `IntVar()`, `IntString()`, etc.. They need to use `.set()`, `.get()` to access value but they can also keep functions which they have to execute when value was changed. I think `kivy` has also similar class - `Property()`

Answer (score 2):

The trick is that you want to monitor the variable in the *caller's* scope, which might be in a different module or in a function. You can use the `inspect` module to get the caller's global and local variables, then evaluate your expression in that scope.

(I have written a simplified version of the class that just monitors the given expression for a change.)

```
import inspect

class Monitor:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __enter__(self):
        frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        self.val = eval(self.name, frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals)
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        val = eval(self.name, frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals)
        if self.val != val:
            print(self.name, "has changed. was", self.val, "now", val)

a = 4
with Monitor("a"):
    a = 3

def test():
    b = 5
    with Monitor("b"):
        b = 6

test()
```

Arguably, a better way is to use a function to capture these values in a closure. Then we don't need magic like `inspect`. We just call the function and see if its value changes. (We do lose the name of the variable, though, unless we explicitly provide that in our function, as shown in the `test()` function below.)

```
class Monitor:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __enter__(self):
        self.val = self.func()
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        val = self.func()
        if self.val != val:
            print("value has changed. was", self.val, "now", val)

a = 4
with Monitor(lambda: a):
    a = 3

def test():
    b = 5
    with Monitor(lambda: f"{b=}"):
        b = 6

test()
```

Comment: Note, this won't work if the variable is in a non-local scope.

Comment: The second version should work with nonlocal variables, which is another reason to prefer it.